# TFS build `Summary Information` text syntax format

Tags: visual-studio-2012, syntax, message, summary

After a build definition is queued and completes, a build summary report/information page is displayed as in the below screen-shot.

I see that there are links and collapsible text in the report.

A google search can find me the syntax for the link as `[link display text](the URL of the link)`

Where can I find the documentation that lists all the syntax for writing messages to the TFS build summary page, e.g. the collapsible text?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no way how to specify other formatting than links:

> As explained, messages can only be text based, this is a limitation of the new activity and model. If you need to add a custom section with more rich content (text, images, graphics…) you will have to use the same method as in the previous version and develop a Visual Studio add-in.

Source:

- [TFS 2012: Add a custom  section in a build summary](http://blog.qetza.net/en/2012/07/09/tfs-2012-add-a-custom-section-in-a-build-summary/)
- [TFS11 RC – Simple Build Summary Customization](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jpricket/archive/2012/06/07/tfs11-rc-simple-build-summary-customization.aspx)